# Passing variables and functions between Powershell forms

Tags: winforms, function, powershell, multiple-forms

I'm making a multiform Powershell toolset with 3 forms in total for now.

- **mainForm.ps1** -   GUI and Functions
- **createForm.ps1**  -  Pure GUI and event handlers passing to createFunctions
- **createFunctions.psm1** - Functions needed to make the script work

The main form simply holds the basic skeleton and a navigation to run the create script.
The create form draws my tool into a section of the main form.
The createFunctions holds the functions needed.

I can run the create form and then, from inside that, import the functions module.

I seem to be able to pass variables and functions through each form, but my issue comes when I try to call a function from within the property:

```
Button.add_click({ })
```

For some reason I can't run a function (located in createFunctions) from any event handler. This is the same for:

```
Textbox.add_textchanged({})
```

I can run the same function (from createFunctions) by putting the exact same function name **outside** the event handler. e.g.:

```
#Doesn't run Test-function
function Set-Stage{
    $runFunctionBtn = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    #Ommitted formatting and behaviour.
    $runFunctionBtn.add_Click({Test-Function})
}
#Does run Test-Function
function Set-Stage{
    $runFunctionBtn = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    #Ommitted formatting and behaviour.
    $runFunctionBtn.add_Click({})
    Test-Function

}
```

After days of trying and researching, I can't find the solution; I feel like I need a .parent or $this to move one step outwards.

The module literally just contains functions, one of which being Test-Function.

I hope I am missing something very obvious. I have seen some Powershell studio code which calls a function, but I'm trying to learn Powershell, not a GUI's existing commands.

Comment: Do you get some error or why _For some reason I cant run a function_? Please add some details why.

Comment: Improved text/grammar.

Comment: `Test-Function : The term 'Test-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At V:\Workbench\CompMGR\modules\CREATE.PS1:396 char:27
+     $NewButton.add_click({Test-Function})
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-Function:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: That's the error I receive, however if I place the Test-Function outside of the add_Click then it runs the function fine.